# Access Pipeline Queue variable in YAML pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, devops, multistage-pipeline

I created a variable called `Test` in Pipeline UI and left the value as blank. So it appeared as shown below.

[image]

I'm trying to access this variable in YAML pipeline but unable to check it's empty value.

I'm trying like this :

```
- variables 
  - name: 'Release'
    ${{  if or(eq(variables['Test'],''), eq(variables['Test'], 'undefined')) }}:
      value: 'Stage'
    ${{  if and(ne(variables['Test'],''), ne(variables['Test'], 'undefined')) }}:
      value: 'Test'
```

The variable `Release` value is always `Stage` whether `Test` variable is empty or any value in it.

I think there must be an easy way to check whether a variable value is empty or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct check would be to use `not(...)` to check if the value is defined. However, it seems you can't use these variables for compile time expressions, maybe because the template is already compiled at this point. Only built-in variables seem to work for expressions.

At least, this always returns empty for me:

```
variables:
  - name: CopyVariable
    value: ${{variables['testvariable']}}
```

You could use [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) instead. Though It would probably be best to use a non-empty string here as a default and restrict the possible values.

```yaml
parameters:
- name: testparam
  type: string
  default: ''

variables:
    # Always empty
  - name: CopyVariable
    value: ${{variables['testvariable']}}
    
    # Works fine
  - name: CopyVariable2
    value: ${{variables['Build.SourceBranch']}}

  - name: ByParameter
    ${{ if not(parameters['testparam']) }}:
      value: 'no param'
    ${{ if not(not(parameters['testparam'])) }}:
      value: 'has param'
      
  - name: ByVariable
    # first one is always empty, second one works.
    value: 'Compile time: ${{variables.testvariable}} -- Runtime: $(testvariable)'

steps:

- script: |
      echo Hello, $(CopyVariable) - $(testvariable)
  displayName: 'Copy Variable'
- script: |
      echo Hello, $(CopyVariable2)
  displayName: 'Copy Variable2'
  
- script: |
      echo Hello, $(ByParameter)
  displayName: 'By Parameter'

- script: |
      echo Hello, $(ByVariable)
  displayName: 'By Variable'
```

Comment: runtime parameters seems to be clean solution for my issue here and it worked as expected. `variables` have so many limitations and not suitable for majority of use cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to need to check if variable is empty you can't do this in YAML. But you can do this in Powershell and logging commands to set variable:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

jobs:
- job: Test
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  variables:
    varOS: $(Agent.OS)
  steps:
    - pwsh: |
        $testVar = ''
        $test = '$(Test)'
        if ($test -eq 'undefined' -or $test -eq '') {
          $testVar = "Stage";
        } elseif ($test -ne 'undefined' -and $test -ne '') {
          $testVar = "Test";
        }
        Write-Host $testVar
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Release;isOutput=true]$testVar"
      name: Initialize
    - pwsh: |
        echo '$(Initialize.Release)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share another method to check if a variable value is empty or not.

Based on my test, the condition could get Queue Variable.

You could check if the variable is empty in Pipeline Job with [Condition.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Here is the Yaml sample：

```
steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script:  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Release;]Stage"
  condition: or(eq(variables['Test'],''), eq(variables['Test'], 'undefined'))

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Release;]Test"
  condition:  and(ne(variables['Test'],''), ne(variables['Test'], 'undefined'))

- script: echo $(Release)
```

'  ' or Empty -> Release: Stage

Not empty -> Release: Test

**Update:**

If you still want to use queue variable in the if expression, you can define a variable in yaml and use it to get the value of the queue variable for judgment.

Here is the example:

```
 variables: 
   - name: aaa
     value: $[variables.test]
   - name: Release
     ${{  if or(eq(variables['aaa'],''), eq(variables['aaa'], 'undefined')) }}:
      value: 'Stage'
     ${{  if and(ne(variables['aaa'],''), ne(variables['aaa'], 'undefined')) }}:
      value: 'Test'
```

Comment: So Queue Variable can only be accessed in `condition` but not else where?

Comment: Hi @Venky.  It seems that the `If expression` couldn't  directly get the queue variables.   I also find another workaround, please check the update.